# How to fix version incompatability in gradle.app

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin

in the gradle file i cant compile the project due incompatability with the line

```
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.0'
```

to fix this isssue, i tried to modify it to v7:28.0.0..but it did not fix the issue
please let me know how to solve it

**code**:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
compileSdkVersion 27
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.kotlindynmaicfragment_v1"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.0'
```

**update**:

in one of the classes i have the follwoing imports:

```
 package com.example.kotlindynmaicfragment_v1

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment
 import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction
 import com.example.kotlindynmaicfragment_v1.Fragments.FragmentLeft
 import com.example.kotlindynmaicfragment_v1.Fragments.FragmentRight
import me.dm7.barcodescanner.zxing.ZXingScannerView
```

Comment: Not my area of expertise, but perhaps you need the repositories definition similar to what's described in this link: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-migration to use version `28.0.0`

Comment: @SamYonnou i have updated the question..wpuld you please have a look

Answer (score 0):

As there was a resent update to gradle version 5.1 and androidx libraries for compatibility so if you have not updated your android studio I would recommend you to update it, give a try to it

Answer (score 0):

Try using classpath for dependencies declaration instead of implementation:

```
classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.0.5.RELEASE")
```

Comment: but in the code posted above i dont hve "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.0.5.RELEASE"...would you please refer to which line should be changed